# What's the difference between an iTunes Account, an iCloud Account, and an Apple ID?

Tags: ios, accounts

I just got a new iPhone 5 from work today, and good heavens!  There is 3 accounts for this thing!  My boss has the iCloud account, I'm supposed to hook up my existing iTunes account to it, and now it's asking me for this Apple ID thing...

I thought they were all one account what happened? And what is the difference between them?

Comment: Seriously what is Apple thinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An iCloud account, iTunes account and Apple ID are all the same thing. Apple just refers to them a bit inconsistently. You can (and typically should) have a single Apple ID for all of them, unless you specifically need to separate them out.

## Account "Types"

### iCloud Account

Typically refers to the Apple ID that is used for iCloud services, such as backup and syncing documents and settings between apps. This is set in **Settings → iCloud → Account**.

### iTunes Account

The Apple ID that you use to purchase downloads from the iTunes, iBooks and App Stores and what syncs your iTunes Match songs, if you use that service. It's set in **Settings → iTunes & App Stores → Apple ID**.

It's important to note that *your purchases are linked to your Apple ID* (although music is now DRM-free), and are *not transferrable to other Apple IDs*. So you should be sure to make all your app, video and music purchases on a single Apple ID to save yourself future headaches.

### iMessage

Your Apple ID is also used for iMessage. Set in **Settings → Messages → Send & Receive**.

## Using Multiple Accounts

You can be signed in to different accounts for each of these services, which can be useful if, for example, you want to have a single family account for iTunes purchases, but keep your iCloud and iMessages separate.

## Other Information

Apple has a few support pages that are helpful for untangling all the intricacies of the Apple ID:

- [Frequently asked questions about Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE37)
- [Where do I use an Apple ID?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE69)
- [Using your Apple ID for Apple services](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895)

Comment: What about facetime?

Comment: @robmathers, What about syncing Notes with iCloud? Normal apple ids (that ends with **gmail.com**) doesn't work for that and we'd need to sign up for another `@icloud` email......